# Preventing DNS tunneling

Tags: dns, proxy, tunnel

I recently viewed a pentesting webinar that demonstrated a DNS tunneling attack.  In the question answer section of the webinar someone asked how such tunneling can be prevented.  The advice was to not allow internal DNS servers to resolve external addresses and to run all such external resolution through a proxy.  Can someone explain why this will prevent the tunneling.  If the client is running something that sends a crafted DNS packet to the proxy with the hidden payload won't it eventually reach the relevant DNS server and be returned to the client via the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
Application-aware proxies are capable of analyzing the content of the packet in an protocol-intelligent way, and can determine whether the payload of a reassembled packet passing through is conformant with the data structures for that protocol. As such, the proxy is aware if you are trying to tunnel HTTP data (for instance) in DNS segments.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing a proxy could do (or indeed something I would do if I were worried about tunneling - and does not require a proxy - only a decent router) - is to simply heavily limit the amount of traffic on port 53.   This would not totally prevent tunnelling, but would greatly reduce its utility.  (For example, allow say 100kbit of data over a 120 second interval. This equates to a maximum throughput of < 100 bytes a second, so you could not get an aweful lot of data out this connection)